# How do I put a UIActivityIndicatorView on top of a NavigationBar button (rightBarButtonItem/leftBarButtonItem)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a Navigation Bar and with a rightBarButtonItem.

When someone clicks this button, I want to put a UIActivityIndicatorView right on top of it, which I can then disable in a callback once I'm done loading whatever it is that is loading.

How would I achieve this?

As it stands I have:

```
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, 64))

navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navBar.translucent = false

navBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.darkGrayColor() ]

self.view.addSubview(navBar)

var buttonRight = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Search"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("goSearch"))

buttonRight.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "056A85")

var navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonRight

navigationItem.title = title

navBar.pushNavigationItem(navigationItem, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)`. Two ways:

1. Switch between two `UIBarButtonItem`s for `rightBarButtonItem`.
2. Switch between two `customView`s for the same `UIBarButtonItem` as `rightBarButtonItem`.